# comparing filtered data: matlab bandpass function vs filter function

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

I'm trying to breakdown how bandpass function makes the filtering and stumped upon this line (after the filter is created).

```
y = signal.internal.filteringfcns.filterData(x,opts);
```

x is the data and opts has the filter structure.
I've been looking around and haven't been able to find anything about `signal.internal.filteringfcns.filterData` function. I compared that output with `filter(opts.FilterObject,x)` and they are not the same.

Next is a minimal working example ([data2.txt](https://yadi.sk/d/kJ_FDvHSx56DkA)).

```
load('data2.txt')

srate=64;
freqrange=[0.4 3.5];

var{1}=freqrange;
var{2}=srate;

m=numel(data2);
x=data2;
R=0.1;%10% of signal
Nr=50;
NR=min(round(m*R),Nr);%At most 50 points
x1=2*x(1)-flipud(x(2:NR+1));%maintain continuity in level and slope
x2=2*x(end)-flipud(x(end-NR:end-1));
x=[x1;x;x2];

opts=signal.internal.filteringfcns.parseAndValidateInputs(x,'bandpass',var);
opts = designFilter(opts);

xx = signal.internal.filteringfcns.filterData(x,opts);
x_fil=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

xx = filter(opts.FilterObject,x);
x_fil2=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

plot([data x_fil x_fil2])
legend('raw','filterData','filter')
```

Here is the plot:

[image: data]

And here are the psd plot of both filtered signal (filtData first).

[image: filtData]
[image: filter]

So, any help on this `...filtData` function or I doing something wrong in my analysis?

Comment: I would remove the sub-functions that you copied from `bandpass.m`, since this is copyrighted code from The MathWorks.

Comment: @rinkert new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958392/comparing-filtered-data3-filtdata-bandpass-vs-filtfilt-with-filter-object-vs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi again :) If you type `edit signal.internal.filteringfcns.filterData`, you can even look at what is inside this `filterData` function. You will see that this function (depending on the options `opts`) will either,

- right zero pad the signal with `N/2` zeros and call `filter`
- call `filtfilt` with the signal

This is also described in the docs of [`bandpass`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bandpass.html#namevaluepairarguments). So probably this zero padding explains why your output of `filter(opts.FilterObject,x)` is different.

You cannot find this function described in the documentation of Matlab since it is part of the internal functions of the signal processing toolbox.