# comparing filtered data3: filtData (bandpass) vs filtfilt with filter object vs filfilt with sos matrix

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

new attempt to understand this.

I'm trying to get what `bandpass` matlab function does.

So digging into the m-files, the filter object is constructed with:

```
opts=signal.internal.filteringfcns.parseAndValidateInputs(x,'bandpass',var);
opts = designFilter(opts);
```

Then, the filtering is done with:

```
y = signal.internal.filteringfcns.filterData(x,opts);
```

Then going into the filterData function, the actual filtering is done with:

```
y = filtfilt(opts.FilterObject,x);
```

because it is an IIR filter.
Now, if I look into the `filtfilt` function, it doesn't have a way to deal with the filter object, only the `b-a`, or the `sos-g` representation are possible. `b-a` representation is really bad, so I tried with the `sos-g` representation, and the results are not the same.

I plotted three signals, filtered with: `filterData`, `filtfilt` with filter object and `filtfilt` with `sos-g` representation. Only the first two are equal.
[image: filtered signals]

Next are the PSD of each signal:
filtData:
[image: filtData]
filtfilt filter object:
[image: filtfilt filter object]
filtfilt sos-g:
[image: filtfilt sos-g]
Notice the greater psd on the lower frequencies on the `sos-g` filter.

So, what does matlab does different when a filter object is used int the `filtfilt` function?

Here there is an example (download [data.txt](https://yadi.sk/d/kJ_FDvHSx56DkA)):

```
load('data.txt')
srate=64; 
freqrange=[0.4 3.5];

x=data(60*64:64*90);

var{1}=freqrange; var{2}=srate;

%% append at the beginning and at the end m=numel(x);
R=0.1;%10% of signal 
Nr=50; 
NR=min(round(m*R),Nr);%At most 50 points 
x1=2*x(1)-flipud(x(2:NR+1));%maintain continuity in level and slope
x2=2*x(end)-flipud(x(end-NR:end-1)); 
x=[x1;x;x2];

%% design filter
opts=signal.internal.filteringfcns.parseAndValidateInputs(x,'bandpass',var); 

opts = designFilter(opts);

%% default filtering 
xx = signal.internal.filteringfcns.filterData(x,opts); 
x_fil=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

%% what default filtering is supposed to do 
xx = filtfilt(opts.FilterObject,x); 
x_fil2=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

[z,p,k]=opts.FilterObject.zpk; 
[sos, g] = zp2sos(z, p, k);

%% default filtering with sos-g method 
xx = filtfilt(sos,g,x); 
x_fil3=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

f=figure;
plot([x_fil x_fil2 x_fil3])
title('default vs ff_D vs ff_{sos}')
legend('filterData','filtfilt_D','filtfilt_{sos}')
grid('on')
```

Comment: have you tried a simpler signal, one that you can predict the results?

Comment: ... haven't though on that. However, filter design depends on data, so I might not have the same behavior...